# Can your buddy die in MGS 5: TPP

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

I've tried searching for this, but was unfortunate. Can your buddies die during missions?

If so - do they die permanently and am I banned from using them in the future? I saw a Tweet (I suppose it was a Tweet) from Hideo saying that they do die permanently, but it was before the game rolled out and I'm wondering how true was that. I do not mean getting killed during any missions (plot kills), if there are any.

I kind of don't want to try this out myself, maybe someone already had this?

Comment: Once any of the buddies hit a damage threshold they get fulton extracted out, besides D-Walker whom is just rebuilt.

Comment: I've only had my buddy suffer serious damage once, but I believe you lose some Bond level with them when it happens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

During one of my attempts at Mission 29, D-Walker was destroyed - so in D-Walker's case atleast, he can be killed.

Thanks to the comments from @Dupree3 and @twobugs I can provide more complete information:

- 'living' Buddies are Fulton extracted once they hit a damage threshold
- D-walker will not be extracted but can be destroyed - it is then rebuilt.
- When a Buddy takes significant damage, your bond level with them decreases.
- Buddies are not permanently killed or permanently destroyed.

Comment: Combining your answer and @Dupree3's comment I think I get the whole picture now. There's just one thing bothering me, was Kojima trolling people about this? I would repost this Tweet if only I could find it, but no luck now...

Comment: probably not a troll I'd say - it's most likely they decided to change how that mechanic works during development (I'm thinking after play-testing) or it was a fake tweet to begin with. These types of mechanic changes aren't uncommon during development - they might have concluded it was too frustrating as you don't have alot of control over certain buddies (quiet for instance) and may lose them due to circumstances outside your control.

Comment: Yep... for reference, The Boss's original character design featured one of her breasts exposed to emphasize her maternal characteristics. Oh, and Metal Gear Rising was originally going to be a mainline prequel where you play as The Boss during WW2, but the dev team thought it would be too much pressure without Kojima directing it, so they went with a complete spin off instead. Things change a lot during development... please don't always assume malice from the devs.

Comment: @jammypeach You can also upgrade your answer with the lost bond level when a buddy is downed - I just happened to see this myself with D-Horse as he got shot down by a tank when I was playing after posting the question.